# Remover tudo antes da ultima ocorrência de um - (traço) regex

Tags: regex, pentaho

Isso é tão simples mas não consigo achar a resposta! Gostaria de eliminar tudo antes da ultima ocorrência do símbolo "-" de uma frase:

Estou utilizando uma step do Pentaho, Replace in String:

**Espressão Regex Utilizada:** `-*[^-]+\d`

**Frase sem Regex:** `Rua Fulano Full, 725 - Bloco1 - 'CEP' - CIDADE Imaginaria/UF`

**Frase com Regex:**  `- Bloco1 - CIDADE Imaginaria/UF`

O resultado que eu queria era apenas a 'cidade/uf' tentei remover os - e então remover a partir dos espaços em brancos, mas já não sei o que fazer. Agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Existe algum requisito para utilizar o regex? Existem maneiras mais simples de resolver. Em java/pentaho seria utilizando o método `split` da classe `String`

Comment: Existe sim, o requisito é fazer o corte no endereço, mas não me refiro apenas a um, mas uma lista com mas de 500 registro, e a melhor maneira de processar esses dados é utilizando a ferramenta Pentaho, porem a mesma oferece suporte a linguagem java, vou realizar os testes com o split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma abordagem sem regex e sem utilizar pentaho.

Em meu exemplo estou usando apenas códigos java. Não é utilizado nenhum "step" do pentaho.

```
String endereco = "Rua Fulano Full, 725 - Bloco1 - 'CEP' - CIDADE Imaginaria/UF";
String[] arrEndereco = endereco.split("-");
String cidadeUF = arrEndereco[arrEndereco.length-1];
System.out.println(cidadeUF.trim());
//CIDADE Imaginaria/UF
```

Neste trecho temos a String que desejamos "extrair" o valor: "cidade/UF", para isso eu transformo a String endereço em uma variável do tipo array através do método [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), "quebrando" esta String pelo caractere <kbd>-</kbd> (hífen).

De posse do array endereço, de acordo com o seu requisito, queremos a última posição do array (que é a informação de Cidade e UF [unidade federativa]), para isso utilizamos o método `length` do tipo primitivo [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7).

Falta agora só fazer a limpeza do dado, removendo os espacos em branco que estão presentes no inicio da string devido ao modo como fizemos a separação da String, para isso usamos o método [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) da classe String.

O conteúdo da variável `cidadeUF`, antes de executar o trim() é:

```
" CIDADE Imaginaria/UF"
```

E após executar o trim() remove-se os espaços em branco antes e depois.

```
"CIDADE Imaginaria/UF"
```

### Outra solução usando o método *substring*

Esta solução visa resolver o mesmo problema, só que aqui estamos "recortando" o valor que desejamos da string original.

Segue o código:

```
String endereco = "Rua Fulano Full, 725 - Bloco1 - 'CEP' - CIDADE Imaginaria/UF";
int pontoRecorte = endereco.lastIndexOf("-");
String cidadeUF = endereco.substring(pontoRecorte+1);
System.out.println(cidadeUF.trim());
//CIDADE Imaginaria/UF
```

1. Encontramos o ultimo índice do "hífen" na String do endereço (utilizando o método [`lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))), que será o ínicio do ponto de recorte.

   ```
   //                                     ↓ ponto de recorte
   "Rua Fulano Full, 725 - Bloco1 - 'CEP' - CIDADE Imaginaria/UF";
   ```
2. Depois é só criar uma nova string do ponto de recorte até o fim da string. É o que a função [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) está fazendo.

   ```
   //                                      ↓ ponto de recorte + 1
   "Rua Fulano Full, 725 - Bloco1 - 'CEP' - CIDADE Imaginaria/UF";
   ```